# Ruby 2.1 Windows 8 Tweetstream

Tags: ruby, windows, openssl

I am trying to run tweetstream on my Windows 8.1 machine and this happened.

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  Encryption not available on this event-machine

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

I installed OpenSSL but no luck.

Anyone has an idea?